# Django Channels HttpClient testing error

Tags: django, django-testing, django-channels

I have been trying to create a test for one of the consumers in channels' multichat example project: https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat. The consumer function looks like this:

```
@channel_session_user
def chat_join(message):
    print(message.content)
    room = get_room_or_error(message[MsgFields.ROOM], message.user)

    if NOTIFY_USERS_ON_ENTER_OR_LEAVE_ROOMS:
        room.send_msg(None, message.user.nickname, message.user.id, MSG_TYPE_ENTER)

    room.websocket_group.add(message.reply_channel)
    message.channel_session[ChannelSession.ROOMS] = list(set(message.channel_session[ChannelSession.ROOMS]).union([room.id]))

    recent_msgs = Message.objects.filter(room=room.id).order_by(ChatModelFields.CREATED_AT)[:10]
    history = []
    for msg in recent_msgs:
        history.append({
            ChatModelFields.CONTENT: msg.content,
            ChatModelFields.CREATOR: msg.creator,
            MsgFields.MSG_TYPE: MSG_TYPE_MESSAGE,
        })

    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text': json.dumps({
            MsgFields.USER_JOIN: str(room.id),
            'history': history,
        })
    })
```

Now, the interesting error I kept running into goes like this. 
In my test function version 1:

```
 def test_chat_send(self):
        user = HubUser.objects.create_user(
            self.TEST_EMAIL,
            password=self.TEST_PASSWORD,
            nickname=self.TEST_NICKNAME
        )
        room = ChatRoom.objects.create(creator=self.TEST_NICKNAME)

        msg_join = {
            MsgFields.ROOM: 1,
            MsgFields.COMMAND: 'join',
        }
        msg_send = {
            MsgFields.MESSAGE: self.TEST_MSG,
            MsgFields.CREATOR: user,
            MsgFields.ROOM: 1,
            MsgFields.COMMAND: 'send',
        }

        c = HttpClient()
        c.login(username=self.TEST_EMAIL, password=self.TEST_PASSWORD)
        c.send_and_consume(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, content=msg_join, fail_on_none=True)
```

The test gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Web\HubService\src\chat\tests\tests.py", line 60, in test_chat_send
    c.send_and_consume(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, content=msg_join, fail_on_none=True)
  File "C:\Users\Doge\Envs\dogeenv\lib\site-packages\channels\tests\base.py", line 127, in send_and_consume
    return self.consume(channel, fail_on_none=fail_on_none)
  File "C:\Users\Doge\Envs\dogeenv\lib\site-packages\channels\tests\base.py", line 118, in consume
    raise AssertionError("Can't find consumer for message %s" % message)
AssertionError: Can't find consumer for message <channels.message.Message object at 0x0000000006086B70>
```

Test function version 2:

```
def test_chat_send(self):
            user = HubUser.objects.create_user(
                self.TEST_EMAIL,
                password=self.TEST_PASSWORD,
                nickname=self.TEST_NICKNAME
            )
            room = ChatRoom.objects.create(creator=self.TEST_NICKNAME)

            msg_join = {
                MsgFields.ROOM: 1,
                MsgFields.COMMAND: 'join',
            }
            msg_send = {
                MsgFields.MESSAGE: self.TEST_MSG,
                MsgFields.CREATOR: user,
                MsgFields.ROOM: 1,
                MsgFields.COMMAND: 'send',
            }

            c = HttpClient()
            c.login(username=self.TEST_EMAIL, password=self.TEST_PASSWORD)
            c.send(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, content=msg_join)
            c.consume(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, fail_on_none=True)
```

The test can now successfully route the message to the correct consumer, but unable to proceed because of user authentication:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Web\HubService\src\chat\tests\tests.py", line 59, in test_chat_send
    c.consume(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, fail_on_none=True)
  File "C:\Users\Doge\Envs\dogeenv\lib\site-packages\channels\tests\base.py", line 116, in consume
    return consumer(message, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doge\Envs\dogeenv\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 64, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doge\Envs\dogeenv\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 42, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "J:\Web\HubService\src\chat\consumers.py", line 38, in chat_join
    room = get_room_or_error(message[MsgFields.ROOM], message.user)
  File "J:\Web\HubService\src\chat\utils.py", line 24, in get_room_or_error
    raise ClientError("User not logged in")
chat.exceptions.ClientError: User not logged in
```

My questions are:

1) Why would calling `HttpClient.send` and `HttpClient.consume` separately produce different behavior than calling `HttpClient.send_and_consume`. I looked at the send_and_consume function and it is just calling send and consume separately like how I did it.

2) How can I make it work so that I wouldn't get the user login error?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answers after some more digging.

1) `send_and_consume` has a different behavior than calling `send` then `consume` because I am using HttpClient here. HttpClient inherits from Client and has it's own implementation of `send` method but it does not implement the `send_and_consume` method. If you call send_and_consume, you are essentially calling `Client.send` and `Client.consume`, but in my case I needed `HttpClient.send` and `Client.consume`.

2) In order to avoid the user login error, I have to initialize a session. Which can be done inside another consumer. In the example it was this:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # Initialise their session
    message.channel_session['rooms'] = []
```

So here's my code after putting all the pieces together:

```
def user_connect(self, client):
    client.send('websocket.connect', path='/chat/stream')
    client.consume('websocket.connect', fail_on_none=True)

def test_chat_join(self):
    user = HubUser.objects.create_user(
        self.TEST_EMAIL,
        password=self.TEST_PASSWORD,
        nickname=self.TEST_NICKNAME
    )
    room = ChatRoom.objects.create(creator=self.TEST_NICKNAME)

    c = HttpClient()
    c.login(username=self.TEST_EMAIL, password=self.TEST_PASSWORD)
    self.user_connect(c)
    msg_join = {
        MsgFields.ROOM: 1,
        MsgFields.COMMAND: 'join',
    }
    c.send(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, content=msg_join)
    c.consume(RECEIVER_CHANNEL, fail_on_none=True)
    # asserts and etc...
```

I hope this helps the people having similar issues.